# How to hide appbar in pageview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to hide my appbar while scrolling pages using pageview.builder. But the appbar doesn't hide while scrolling the pages.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../Controller/NewsController.dart';
import 'Export.dart';

class ShowNewsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowNewsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ShowNewsPage> createState() => _ShowNewsPageState();
}

class _ShowNewsPageState extends State<ShowNewsPage> {
  bool _init = true;
  bool _isLoadingNews = false;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    if (_init) {
      _isLoadingNews =
          await Provider.of<NewsController>(context, listen: false).getNews();
    }
    _init = false;
    setState(() {});
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final news = Provider.of<NewsController>(context).allNews;
    if (!_isLoadingNews) {
      return const Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
    } else {
      return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        body: NestedScrollView(
          floatHeaderSlivers: true,
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
            SliverAppBar(
              floating: true,
              title: Text('Next'),
              centerTitle: true,
              toolbarHeight: 40,
            ),
          ],
          body: PageView.builder(
            physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: news.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            // shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return NewNewscardWidget(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                title: news[index].title!.rendered!,
                content: news[index].content!.rendered!,
                image: news[index].ogImage ?? [],
                id: news[index].id!,
                // authorName: news[index].author!,
                date: 'November 5, 2022',
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I want the Appbar to hide while I scroll the pages downwards and want it to reappear if I drag the page up a bit. The code I have implemented in the SliverAppbar works perfectly fine for Listview.builder but doesn't work for Pageview.builder. Is it possible to hide the appbar in Pageview.builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that is pageView, you need to create a `PageController` and attach a listener to it that listens to the scrolling and hides the appbar when scrolling. I have created a sample here for you.

```html
class ShowNewsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowNewsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ShowNewsPage> createState() => _ShowNewsPageState();
}

class _ShowNewsPageState extends State<ShowNewsPage> {
  late PageController _pageViewController;
  bool _showAppbar = true;
  bool isScrollingDown = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageViewController = PageController();
    _pageViewController.addListener(() {
      if (_pageViewController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.reverse) {
        if (!isScrollingDown) {
          isScrollingDown = true;
          _showAppbar = false;
          setState(() {});
        }
      }

      if (_pageViewController.position.userScrollDirection ==
          ScrollDirection.forward) {
        if (isScrollingDown) {
          isScrollingDown = false;
          _showAppbar = true;
          setState(() {});
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageViewController.dispose();
    _pageViewController.removeListener(() {});
    super.dispose();
  }

  final bool _isLoadingNews = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isLoadingNews) {
      return const Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
    } else {
      return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        body: NestedScrollView(
          floatHeaderSlivers: true,
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
            SliverAppBar(
              floating: true,
              title: const Text('Next'),
              centerTitle: true,
              toolbarHeight: _showAppbar ? 40 : 0.0,
            ),
          ],
          body: PageView.builder(
            controller: _pageViewController,
            physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: 5,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .80,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .80,
                child: const Center(child: Text('item')),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```